# How to pass variable in js from serverside to clientside in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a project like skribble.io for school using pubnub and nodejs.
base code from [Guesswordpubnub](https://github.com/ocastroa/GuessWordPubNub).
In pubnub we need to provide a channel for lobby like connection.
I implemented the pubnub things in client side scripts
and my code:

in serverside "routename.js":

```
router.get("/:link", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("playground");
  var lobbyName = req.params.link;
});
```

and now in client side i am simply prompting for a name

```
  let lobby = prompt("Enter name of lobby");
```

how can i pass the `lobbyName` from server to client side `lobby`

I don't know what to do.If it is stupid question, pardon

I am a beginner. only familiar with vanilla js
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables directly to your view by doing something like this:

```
router.get("/:link", function (req, res, next) {
  let lobbyName = req.params.link;
  res.render("playground", {lobbyName: lobbyName});
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can i use the variable in the js when  i am using the the <script src="/javascripts/lobby.js"> in the view

Answer (score 1):

In routername.js:

```
router.get("/:link", function (req, res, next) {
  let lobbyName = req.params.link;
  res.render("playground", {lobbyName: lobbyName});
});
```

in the view `playground` i am using external js file so **before** the script src tag i **should** mention `<script>var lobby ={{lobbyName}}</script>`

so the playground.hbs:

```
<script>var lobby ={{lobbyName}}</script>
<script src="/javascripts/lobby.js" ></script>
```